# IISvdir.vbs To create virtual directory in IIS6

Tags: iis-6

If I use following command to create virtual directory under root of my site named "Images" it works:
`CSCRIPT %systemroot%\system32\IISvdir.vbs /create "TestWeb" "Images" "D:\MyImages"`
I have http://mysite/Images

If I have a folder under root of my side named "Folder1" but I want to create virtual directory inside Folder1 like http://mysite/Folder1/Images by using
`CSCRIPT %systemroot%\system32\IISvdir.vbs /create "TestWeb" "Folder1/Images" "D:\MyImages"`
Then I got Alias contains invalid character(s). error message.

Is there a way I can use command line to create nested virtual directory in IIS6?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution that to use `CSCRIPT %systemroot%\system32\IISvdir.vbs /create "TestWeb/Folder1" "Images" "D:\MyImages"` instead.